# Firebase загрузка с realDataBase

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, swift3

Как можно загрузить только те даные которие были добавлены, изменены или обновлены?
грузить все даные очень долго, а метода в офц доке не нашел[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
func loadCDDAta(completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {


    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in


         if snapshot.exists() && snapshot.value != nil {

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        self.deleteRecords()

        if let f = value?["Place"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

            CoreDataManager.instance.saveCDDict(f)
        }

        else if let f = value?["Place"] as? [AnyObject] {

            CoreDataManager.instance.saveCDArray(f)

        }

        completionHandler(true)
            print("completionHandler(true)")

        } else {

            completionHandler(false)
             print("completionHandler(false)")

        }

    }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in

        completionHandler(false)
        print("completionHandler(false)")

    })

}
```

Comment: что такое загрузить в вашем контексте?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190095/max-mikheyenko
витащить и записать в CoreData

Comment: вытащить откуда?

Comment: max-mikheyenko
c realDataBase

Comment: прочитать даные

Comment: короче вам надо с сервера получить только то, что было обновлено с момента последнего получения данных вашим клиентом?

Comment: да и дописить их до существующих даных в coreData или изменить их если чтото было удалено или изменено в realDataBase